# Join 2 files by common column header (without awk/sed)

Tags: linux, unix, join, text-processing, gnu-coreutils

Basically I want to get all records from `file2`, but filter out columns whose header doesn't appear in `file1`

**Example**:

file1

```
Name Location
```

file2

```
Name Phone_Number Location Email
Jim  032131       xyz      xyz@qqq.com
Tim  037903       zzz      zzz@qqq.com
Pimp 039141       xxz      xxz@qqq.com
```

Output

```
Name Location
Jim  xyz
Tim  zzz
Pimp xxz
```

Is there a way to do this without `awk` or `sed`, but still using `coreutils` tools? I've tried doing it with `join`, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself so much? `awk` is perfectly suited: `join` certainly is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @glennjackman Partly curiosity, partly cause I want to learn the limitations of the other text-processing tools (I know how to do it in `awk`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALL_COLUMNS=$(head -n1 file2)
for COLUMN in $(head -n1 file1); do
    JOIN_FORMAT+="2.$(( $(echo ${ALL_COLUMNS%%$COLUMN*} | wc -w)+1 )),"
done
join -a2 -o ${JOIN_FORMAT%?} /dev/null file2
```

---

### Explanation:

```
ALL_COLUMNS=$(head -n1 file2)
```

It saves all the column names to filter next

---

```
for COLUMN in $(head -n1 file1); do
    JOIN_FORMAT+="2.$(( $(echo ${ALL_COLUMNS%%$COLUMN*} | wc -w)+1 )),"
done
```

For every column in `file1`, we look for the position of the one with the same name in `file2` and append it to `JOIN_FORMAT` in the way of `"2.<number_of_column>,"`

---

```
join -a2 -o ${JOIN_FORMAT%?} /dev/null file2
```

Once we have the option string complete (`2.1,2.3,`), we pass it to `join` removing the last `,`.

`join` prints the unpairable lines from the second file provided (`-a2 -> file2`), but only the columns specified in the `-o` option.

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient, but works for your example:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -a cols < file1
echo "${cols[@]}"

read -r -a header < <(head -n1 file2)
keep=()
for (( i=0; i<${#header}; i++ )) ; do 
    for c in "${cols[@]}" ; do
        if [[ ${header[i]} == "$c" ]] ; then
            keep+=($i)
        fi
    done
done

while read -r -a data ; do
    for idx in ${keep[@]} ; do
        printf '%s ' "${data[idx]}"
    done
    printf '\n'
done < <(tail -n+2 file2)
```

Tools used: `head` and `tail`. They aren't essential, though. And `bash`, of course.